# cross origin video does not load in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, cors

I am trying to get my video with `crossorigin` attribute play in Chrome (version 20.0.1132.47 m). It does not even load. The network panel shows that the `OPTIONS` (so called "preflight") request gets aborted by the browser for some reason.It works without the `crossorigin` attribute. Firefox loads and plays it successfully. I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
<video
    id='vid'
    autoplay
    crossorigin
    src='http://videos-cdn.mozilla.net/serv/mozhacks/demos/resources/immersivevideo/dubai.r.webm'>
</video>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZVgr2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of this turned out to be missing `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header with the list of HTTP headers that matches the list passed in `Access-Control-Request-Headers` request header.

Comment: Can you please share how to implement exactly?

Comment: Here is a SO post that has an answer that implements `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to be the same as `Access-Control-Request-Headers` in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/410102

Comment: I don't suppose there are any "simple" client side solutions - I'm just trying to get a videojs instance to load caption`.vtt` files hosted on `localhost` in Chrome.

Comment: what hosts the javascript file itself that tries to open the cation file?

Answer (score 2):

In the video tag set `crossorigin` to `"anonymous"` like this:

```
 <video crossorigin="anonymous"></video>
```

Comment: OMG one of my Chrome extensions was adding this to all my videos and was breaking video playback behavior in my dev apps. Took forever to find it! Argh! In this case the extension was: Audio EQ Equalizer for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

In case this is helpful to anyone else, I was having the same issue after supposedly fixing the CORS settings on the source file. Turns out Chrome was caching the CORS setting along with the file, so I had to clear the cache and then it worked.

Comment: Thank you, that did it for me. I've added `crossorigin="anonymous"` to my `<audio>` and got the error. Then, thanks to your answer, I've pressed Command + Shift + R on Chrome on Mac and the error was gone.